# Moving a RoR project from self hosted svn to github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, github

We have a RoR project, which we host on self hosted svn and use Redmine for issue tracking. I am the only technical core team member and haven't used git before. We have hired a developer last week who also haven't worked with git. We outsource some of our work to a vendor, who works mainly on git, but screws up the branching, rebasing and commits sometimes on svn.

I am thinking of switching to github, mainly because it will remove the headache of admining svn and redmine and have heard a lot of coll things about git and particularly github.

I this is sensible think to do? If your answer is yes, how can I migrate my svn repository to github? we have directory structure like following:

```
project
  - trunk
  - branches
```

Some of the branches have ongoing incomplete work and I can't imagine that there will be no active branches the way we have been working.

*Addition:* Please let me know, how would the work flow and repository management will change if I make the switch?

Comment: may be usefull for what you want : https://github.com/blog/156-subversion-importing

Comment: But they say the sync is one time only, its not on continuous basis. I might need some time to transition completely to git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently moved my team in India to github from SVN.  I used [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git). After setting up the svnusers file, all of the commit history was preserved and mapped nicely to the developers github accounts.

Another positive of using svn2git was that during the transition period, we actually had active development on both svn and git repos.  I was able to use

svn2git --rebase

to pull commits from the subversion repo and apply them in git.  Then I could git push those to github.  That only works one-way, but that was fine for us as we we weren't interested in pulling changes from git back into svn, only in making sure to incorporate the work from the subversion stragglers.